# Can't set sales tax in QuickBooks Sales Order using API v2

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

How do I specify the sales tax AMOUNT when inserting a sales order or invoice in QBD using REST API v2?

I'm updating an app that uses QBD API v2. We need to add the sales tax amount to sales orders and invoices. The doc is very weak regarding sales taxes, and in some cases is flat out wrong (it references the company's federal tax ID, which has nothing to do with sales tax).

No matter what I do, after I sync the order to QBD, the order has the sales tax calculated automatically by QB using the default tax location. It ignores all the tax info in my API call. I've added a tax line and filled in every tax field I could find, but nothing works.

Note that we need to specify the AMOUNT rather than letting QB calculate tax, because the sales transaction is coming from another application, which has already calculated the tax amount. So we have to use the actual amount collected from the customer, even if it's wrong for some reason. This follows the model of QBPOS integration with QB (using QBSDK). Unfortunately the REST API is much less clear than the SDK.

Does anybody have sample code which sets the tax amount on a transaction?

Comment: Hi Mike, As you know that V2 is deprecated already. But in this case, why don't you create a transaction in QBD by setting desired tax amount and retrieve the same using V2(getById). That way, we'll find out the object structure/behavior. Thanks

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I'll try that after World Cup...

Comment: @mkittel, I don't see how that can be done in the UI too. Looks like a limitation of the UI. You can however create a an item with desc as tax and enter the flat amount against it for your use case.

Comment: Well, this just isn't working. I added a tax line to a QB sales order and then queried it via the API to see what it looks like. Created a new Sales Order to match that, and it inserts and syncs OK, but the tax doesn't show up in QB, just the sales order with no tax.